# Using the qgis2web plugin to export layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

Using the qgis2web plugin on QGIS Desktop, is it possible to export the layers to an HTML file that already exists?

I already know how to use QGIS server. I'm trying not to use a server for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. It sounds like a nice feature request though.

For now you would need to extract the code and data from the export as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the existing page is. If it's static HTML/JS/CSS, create a new qgis2web template using that code - they are saved in `.qgis2/qgis2web`. **Do not just edit one of the existing templates** (`full-screen` or `canvas-size`), as these are overwritten when the plugin is upgraded, and you would lose your template.

Alternatively, just use the full-screen template, and then pull it into the existing page via an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the layer are the same and their attributes are the same this is very straightforward.

You just need to update the .js files in the /layers folder.

Answer (score 0):

I finished project in Qgis and would like export to my webpage.

But surpise - I had try export to html with Leaflet. There are not Tile layers, raster layer, there are not showing images on mouse over,...there are lot of problems.
Only OSM and few vectors layers, very poor menu,....
Before I will start investigating -is another(better) plugin for web export?If no i need go step by step with leaflet. I hope that there is easier way.
Thanks

Qgis project all is working -tiles, rasters, mouse over,...:

[image]

Export:
[image]